# How to join three table using inner join in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, join

I am trying to get the data from the three table using inner join but its sows me empty result.

```
select comp.gps_time as complaint_register_date,comp.accept_date as complaint_accept_date,comp.name as citizen_name,comp.road_id,dept.dept_name,circle.circle_name,division.div_name 
from complaints as comp 
   INNER JOIN department as dept ON dept.dept_code=comp.dept_code 
   INNER JOIN circle as circle on circle.circle_code=comp.circle_code 
   INNER JOIN division as division on division.div_code=comp.div_code  
where comp.templateid != null
```

> complaint table

```
Complaint_Id    Roadid  Dept_code   Div_code    Circle_code Name    Templateid  Accept_date             Gps_time
162            167889       3         1             4        Xyz       3        2019-02-25 09:40:39        2019-02-23 09:40:39
168            167880       2         4             6        abc     null       2019-02-25 09:40:39       2019-02-23 09:40:39
```

> Department table

```
Dept_code   Dept_name
3           Abcdept
2           Zyzdept
1           syzdept
```

> Circle table

```
Circle_code Circle_name
4           Xcircle
6           ycircle
```

> Division Table

```
Division_code   Division_name
1                Ydiv
2                ndiv
4                zdiv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test for null using `=` or `<>` (or `!=`)

To test for non-null values you need to use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
where comp.templateid is not null
```